# Create the same subfolders in another folder with copying files with certain names

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

I have a directory which has many sub-folders and under sub-folders there are other sub-folders. I want to copy all the directory and subdirectories into another location with copying only files with certain names in these directories (while preserving the hierarchy).

Let's say, copy all the directory and sub-directories, then if these directories have files with `.txt` extensions, copy them too.

What is the best way to do this on a Unix/Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync -a --include='*/' --include='*.txt' --exclude='*' source_dir/ target_dir
```

This should create a copy of the `source_dir` directory hierarchy as `target_dir`, with files whose names match `*.txt` copied (only).

The `--include` and `--exclude` options are handled in a left-to-right fashion and the first pattern that matches a name "wins". The way these options are used here ensures that all directories are processed, as well as any name matching `*.txt`, but ignores everything else.

The `-a` (`--archive`) option ensures that the `source_dir` hierarchy is processed recursively, and that as much as possible of file meta data is preserved in the copy (see the `rsync` manual for details).

Comment: Thank you! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the (absolute) destination directory exists:

```
mkdir -p "$DST_DIR"
```

Go to the source directory (it shouldn't be a descendant or parent of $DST_DIR):

```
cd "$SRC_DIST"
```

Re-create the directory structure (this will fail if you have directories with '\n' in their names):

```
find . -type d -print | xargs -I% mkdir -p "$DST_DIR"/%
```

Copy the interesting files there (in this example: *.txt and *.h):

```
find . \( -name \*.txt -o -name \*.h \) -print0 | cpio -pvdm0 "$DST_DIR"
```

#### SIDE NOTE

If don't want directories that don't contain target files, you could just do:

```
find . \( -name \*.txt -o -name \*.h \) -print0 \
| cpio -pvdm0 $DST_DIR
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed your answer after seeing the following solution and selecting it .